# Integration test an API whose behavior depends on the current time

Tags: java, rest, testing, time, integration-testing

I have a few APIs I'm trying to thoroughly ***integration*** test -- I'm hitting the remote service which is running in a test environment (not the same box that is running the tests, the tests make real service calls), I can't just use dependency injection to solve all my problems. We already have a good suite of unit tests on these classes.

The API I'm testing is SaveThingy. It saves a Thingy if it's valid, and returns you the id of it. One of the checks is that you can only save a thingy at certain times, say only on weekdays. If you call SaveThingy on the weekend, it insults you personally instead of saving a Thingy. The implementation looks something like the following

```
ThingyId saveThingy(Thingy thingy) {
    if (isWeekend(LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek())) {
        throw new PersonalInsultException("your mother wears army boots");
    }
    return thingyDao.save(thingy);
}
```

I'd ideally like to have both cases tested each time we run integration tests, without any waiting. In some code, I want tests similar to the following to run each time.

```
@Test
public void saveThingy_validThingyOnWeekday_savesThingy() {
    ThingyId id = serviceUnderTest.saveThingy(THINGY);
    assertThat(serviceUnderTest.getThingyById(id)).isEqualTo(THINGY);
}

@Test(expected = PersonalInsultException.class)
public void saveThingy_validThingyOnWeekend_receivePersonalInsult() {
    serviceUnderTest.saveThing(THINGY);
}
```

Are there any standard ways that allow complete testing of such APIs? I've considered a few options (below), but wanted to get additional opinions.

1. say no to integration testing, live with only unit tests for these APIs
2. change the remote clock, either using a private API or by literally ssh-ing into the host before running each test
3. write tests that are time dependent; only testing one of the possible behaviors, or testing one behavior then sleeping until other conditions are met
4. invent dummy data that will always save or always throw an exception

Comment: Why not inject the time to whatever your tests need?

Comment: @oldercoder How? The code is running remotely (not the same box as the one running the tests).

Comment: @Hugo How would I inject a Clock into remotely running code?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this detail. Well, if you have no control over the date on remote service, then the test should check the result according to the current date - which is your option 3, I guess: `if (isWeekend) { check if exception was thrown } else { check saved thingy }`

Comment: When you say you covered it in Unit Tests, you mean really "100%" unit tests, with absolutely everything mocked?

Comment: @VitorSantos Pretty much, yes. We don't mock literally everything (we typically go by "inject in, mock out"), but we were able to unit test this class fully.

Comment: @twentylemon, why not do a "middle" integration test instead of a full remote integration test? It's possible do write a test case that connects to a database and and to check if the data was correctly inserted. Then the only thing you would mock would be the current date/time. Then you would be sure that all your layers are correctly integrated, without the need to worry about the remote integration testing complexity.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose in your `ThingyService` class you have a public
or protected `isWeekend` method. Probably something like this:

```
public boolean isWeekend(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
    return dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
}
```

In your `ThingyServiceTest` you can then create two specialized `ThingyService` instances with mocked `isWeekend` methods.
In your test-cases you can use either of these:

```
// service with weekday behavior
private ThingyService serviceUnderTest_weekday = new ThingyService() {
    @Override
    public boolean isWeekend(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
        return false;
    }
};

// service with weekend behavior
private ThingyService serviceUnderTest_weekend = new ThingyService() {
    @Override
    public boolean isWeekend(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
        return true;
    }
};

@Test
public void saveThingy_validThingyOnWeekday_savesThingy() {
    ThingyId id = serviceUnderTest_weekday.saveThingy(THINGY);
    assertThat(serviceUnderTest_weekday.getThingyById(id)).isEqualTo(THINGY);
}

@Test(expected = PersonalInsultException.class)
public void saveThingy_validThingyOnWeekend_receivePersonalInsult() {
    serviceUnderTest_weekend.saveThing(THINGY);
}
```

Comment: We already have a good suite of unit tests where we have stubbed out the current time. The question is about integration testing, where it's not possible to stub out the time since the code under test is not running on the same machine as the test code.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to achieve black box testing with white box testing requirements: it's simply not possible. Stick to white box testing and mock out your DateProvider locally. Maybe not what you want to hear but you will waste so much time otherwise trying to align the stars to produce the output you want in your assertion.

Now on the other hand if you really want to do this run your application inside a docker container and change the system clock then just tear it down between tests.

Alternatively open up a separate endpoint which allows to specify the current time via your service and only deploy this endpoint when you are testing. Or have a configuration interface responsible for determining the source of your current time and when you deploy to your test environment configure the app accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `LocalDate.now()` or `Instant.now()` or `Whatever.now()` or passing `long` timestamps, consider adding `java.time.Clock` field to your class, and either add an initialization parameter to constructor or provide a setter.

`Clock.instant()` is essentially `Instant.now()`, and you can convert the instant into any other temporal class.

In production, you will use `Clock.systemUTC()` as the value of that field.
In some tests, you can use `Clock.fixed()`, and in all tests you can just mock the way you need it for tests.

This approach is mostly suited for unit tests. You can still inject your custom `Clock` implementation in integration environment, so that the application as a whole will think that the current time is whatever you need.